# Moving out of US. What are my options for investment accounts?

Tags: mutual-funds

I am a non-resident alien who is moving out of USA to Canada or India. I have my investment accounts which require me to have a valid USA address. What are my investment options at this point with USA assets assuming I don't want to move the money out of country as of yet.

Comment: Options would depend on where you are moving. Some countries will have similar fund choices. You will also have to describe your accounts: IRA, 401(k), taxable...

Comment: I want to check for both India and Canada.

Comment: I think you should ask two separate questions.  The rules for India are quite strict and vary significantly depending on whether you are a resident or non-resident.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how much your account is worth. If it has $10,000 you may have a problem finding someone to hold a foreign account. If it has over $100,000 there are a lot of options. Most private banks and "trust" banks will be willing to open accounts for investors with over $100,000 in assets. If you have less than that, I would not bother with trying to maintain a US account and just open an account in whatever country you moved to. Most major banks in foreign countries support dollar denominated accounts.

Comment: Do we have any tax implications for that? Assume Canada in this case. Is there a documentation I can read up on this? Thanks!

Answer (score -12):

If you're not wedded to [mutual-funds](/questions/tagged/mutual-funds), crypto has become mainstream, and is experiencing solid growth this time, without the ICO mania of 2017.

[image: Bitcoin chart YTD 2020]

Presumably you're new to crypto. A very safe way to start is to look at crypto reputable exchanges that allow staking (for example [Coinbase](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/other/staking-on-coinbase) and [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/en-us/features/staking-coins). You'll get an interest rate in addition to the underlying asset simply increasing in value.

Crypto doesn't have idiotic geographical restrictions. And you can also avoid volatility by holding stablecoins (pegged to the dollar).

As you learn more about it, you can become your own bank and hold your own coins [securely](https://blog.kraken.com/post/219/security-advisory-mobile-phones/). Then you won't have KYC restrictions either.

Once you're comfortable with crypto, look into Decentralized Finance ([DeFi](https://www.financemagnates.com/cryptocurrency/news/defi-in-2020-is-decentralized-finance-really-ready-for-the-mainstream/)). Very soon, it will blow traditional investments out of the water. (It already does, but ordinary folks just aren't aware of it.) In August, the [volume traded on the most popular decentralized exchange, exceeded that of Coinbase](https://cointelegraph.com/news/defi-explosion-uniswap-surpasses-coinbase-pro-in-daily-volume), the most popular US exchange.

Next, look into [yield farming](https://www.coindesk.com/defi-yield-farming-comp-token-explained). You'll find far more interesting (end empowering) investment options than mutual funds.

Comment: I also hear dutch tulips are safe ways to double your money.